# SQL FullText Indexes and SQL Injection

Tags: mysql, sql-server, full-text-search, sql-injection, denial-of-service

Is there any known danger with exposing the use of a FullText index to internal and possibly public users?

Assuming the queries are properly parameterized, is there any way that a user could abuse the inputs to trigger a SQL injection or denial of service attack?

```
// SQL Server
select * from content_table WHERE CONTAINS((Title, Subtitle, Body), @fullTextSearch);

// MySQL
select * from content_table WHERE MATCH(Title, Subtitle, Body) AGAINST (@fullTextSearch);

// Oracle
select * from content_table WHERE CONTAINS(Body, @fullTextSearch);
```

The trigger for this question is the large variety of inputs a user could specify and the fact that the different SQL servers have different query syntax and at least some (MySQL) will return a syntax error if an invalid query is specified.

- 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, model NEAR airplane)'
- 'NEAR((term1, term2),5) AND term3'
- 'NEAR((term1, term2),5) OR NEAR((term3, term4),2, TRUE)'
- '+join +(>left <right)'
- 'electric INPATH (/purchaseOrder/items/item/comment)'

Comment: How are you executing these queries? If they're actually parameterized you can't inject, as you have no injection. If you have a stored procedure that injects then you've got problems and executing a stored procedure with placeholders is meaningless at that point. You've got an exploitable injection bug.

Comment: "Denial of Service" is a completely different threat vector than SQL injection. In this case you'd probably solve it by rate limiting.

Comment: @tadman, Using C# with correctly parameterized queries.  My concern is that the spec for what is allowed in a full-text query parameter is sufficiently large that the surface area for abuse is now real.   Compare what is allowed with LIKE vs what is allowed with a CONTAINS.

Comment: You're going to have to be *way* more specific here. How are you allowing arbitrary content to filter into that `CONTAINS`? You should be allowing very, very specific forms with parameterized data in very specific positions and *absolutely nothing else*. If you're injecting, you've got injection bugs. If you're not injecting, you probably don't.

Comment: You'll probably need something that converts the incoming search criteria into the right template with the requisite number of placeholders in it, for example `NEAR ((?, ?), ?) AND ?` instead of what you have there with literal terms baked in.

Comment: @tadman, By arbitrary content, I mean that a user can enter some very complex queries.  Examples provided.  Each example is something that a user can enter directly.   That is part of the power of FullText queries.  Sort of similar to the way you can do advanced queries using Google.

Comment: If you're talking specifically about things that are *string values* then there's no risk of SQL injection, as in `AGAINST(?)`. I can't speak specifically to the other forms as those don't appear to be MySQL at all.

Comment: @tadman, If you summarize your comments into an answer then I will give it to you.  Specifically your first two comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about SQL injection the risk is that someone can introduce SQL keywords into the query itself by adding SQL to a data parameter.

This is why separation of data and query is absolutely critical. This normally plays out by using *placeholder values*, as in:

```sql
SELECT * FROM content_table WHERE MATCH(Title, Subtitle, Body) AGAINST (?);
```

In the case of search there's often two levels you need to be aware of:

- The SQL layer where you're using raw SQL keywords to express the query conditions, such as `WHERE x=? AND y=?`
- The search layer where you're expressing conditions *within a string*, like `WHERE CONTAINS(?)` which has a bound data parameter `'"computer software" NEAR hardware)'`

Note that the second form has a syntax within a string, so if you're exposing that you're not at risk of SQL injection per-se, but you may end up receiving a lot of syntax errors caused by bad user input that you need to handle.

In the first case if you need to compose the query conditions you need to follow the usual rules:

- Do not permit:

  - Inclusion of unknown fields into the query.
  - Inclusion of unknown operators into the query.
- Maintain as strict a separation between query and data as is practical.

You may need to parse the request's data into components that can be recomposed into a SQL query. This can get messy, especially if you're allowing a lot of latitude in how things can be searched, so try and keep it as simple *and testable* as possible.

If you have unit tests, include one that's deliberately hostile and tries to introduce invalid or injection-type data into the query. Ensure the data is properly contained.

> Note: If you're calling a stored procedure using placeholder values, but the stored procedure composes SQL statements using concatenation you're still at risk, so you need to be absolutely certain you're keeping the data separated from the query. If you have a query with *zero* user data introduced in it there is no risk of SQL injection.